# Minimum value of $(\frac{1}{a}-1)(\frac{1}{b}-1)(\frac{1}{c}-1)$

Tags: contest-math

> If $a,b$ and $c$ are positive real numbers such that $a+b+c=1$, what
> is the minimum value of
> $(\frac{1}{a}-1)(\frac{1}{b}-1)(\frac{1}{c}-1)$ ?

How can we solve this? I tried to simplify the expression but still can't figure a way to solve this.

My simplified expression : $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}-1$

Comment: Hint: $1-a = b+c$. (Yes I know this is obvious, but given that this is a hint, how can you use the hint?)

Comment: Hint: AM-GM inequality.

Comment: @IraeVid perhaps not for OP.

Comment: AM-HM inequality gives the answer using your simplified expression  (without using $1-a=b+c$). The asnwer is $8$.

Comment: @IraeVid Oh, I just realized that it is indeed the simplified expression (though ideally the work should be shown). $\quad$ Geetha's comment makes sense with that context.

Comment: This can be also solved with Cauchy's inequality (or Titu's lemma).

Comment: $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}-1\geq \frac{(1+1+1)^2}{a+b+c}-1=8$

Comment: @Ganit FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Ba%7D-1)(%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bb%7D-1)(%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bc%7D-1)%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24a%2Bb%2Bc%3D1%24&p=1), there's not only the proposed duplicate, but also the basically same [The minimum value of $(\frac{1}{x}-1)(\frac{1}{y}-1)(\frac{1}{z}-1)$ if $x+y+z=1$](/q/173492) (with this requiring the values be distinct) and the similar [Find the maximum and minimum of $(1/x-1)(1/y-1)(1/z-1)$ if $x+y+z=1$](/q/3720866).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
(\frac{1}{a}-1)(\frac{1}{b}-1)(\frac{1}{c}-1)
&=\frac{1}{abc}-\frac{1}{ab}-\frac{1}{bc}-\frac{1}{ca}+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}-1 \\
&=\frac{1-a-b-c}{abc}+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}-1 \\
&=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}-1 \\
&\geq\frac{3}{\frac{a+b+c}{3}}-1 & \text{by AM-HM}\\
&=9-1 \\
&=8
\end{align}$$

with equality if and only if $a=b=c$.

Comment: Plese do not answer duplicate questions !

Comment: @Peter When did I post duplicate questions? Give me my upvote back.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{1}{a}-1=\frac{1-a}{a}=\frac{b+c}{a}=\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{a}$$

Similarly,

$$\frac{1}{b}-1=\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{b}$$

$$\frac{1}{c}-1=\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{c}$$

$\therefore  \left(\frac{1}{a}-1 \right)\left(\frac{1}{b}-1 \right)\left(\frac{1}{c}-1 \right)$
$=\left(\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{a}\right)\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{b}\right)\left(\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{c}\right)$

$\ge \left(2 \sqrt{\frac{bc}{a^2}} \right) \left(2 \sqrt{\frac{ca}{b^2}} \right) \left(2 \sqrt{\frac{ab}{c^2}} \right)$

$=8$

Equality holds

iff $\frac{b}{a}=\frac{c}{a},\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{b} $ and $\frac{a}{c}=\frac{b}{c}$

iff $a=b=c$.

Comment: I originally wanted to post this but since I saw OP's "$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}-1$" I decided to continue with his method. Still, +1 clean proof!

Answer (score 1):

The answers posted all uses QM-AM-GM-HM Inequality, so this is an alternative Cauchy-Schwarz proof by making use of the fact that $a+b+c=1$.

As OP has pointed out, the expression $(\frac{1}{a}-1)(\frac{1}{b}-1)(\frac{1}{c}-1)$ simplifies to $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}-1$.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}-1
&=(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c})(a+b+c)-1 \\
&\geq(1+1+1)^2-1 &\text{by Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality}\\
&=9-1 \\
&=8
\end{align}$$

Equality is achieved if and only if $\frac{\frac{1}{a}}{a}=\frac{\frac{1}{b}}{b}=\frac{\frac{1}{c}}{c}$, i.e. $a=b=c=\frac{1}{3}$.